# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework Database not being created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to build a phonebook in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework but my code is not generating the database:

I have the following classes:

Contact.cs

```
    public class Contact
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public String fName { get; set; }
        public String lName { get; set; }
        public String phoneNumber { get; set; }
        public PhoneType phoneType { get; set; }

    }
```

PhoneType.cs

```
    public class PhoneType
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public String type { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
    }
```

ContactDbContext.cs

```
public class ContactDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ContactDbContext() : base("name=ContactDbContextConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ContactDbContext>(new ContactDbInitializer());
    }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PhoneType> PhoneTypes { get; set; }

}
```

ContactDbInitializer.cs

```
public class ContactDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ContactDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ContactDbContext context)
    {
        Contact a = new Contact()
        {
            fName = "Andra",
            lName = "Avram",
            phoneNumber = "604-788-5659"
        };

        a.phoneType.type = "cell";

        context.Contacts.Add(a);
        context.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

In Web.config I have the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ContactDbContextConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=PhonebookDb;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=phonebookContext-20180621103305; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|phonebookContext-20180621103305.mdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I run the application, the database files are not being created.

Can you please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to enable migration, add migration and then update database via command line on package manager console. See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2)

Comment: I'm not using migrations. I'm building the database each time the program is run.

Comment: And how do you expect it to do that? Magic?

Comment: Running the program has nothing to do with generating the database.. you need to enable migrations like penleychan suggested.. then you can add migrations, update database and then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. The program didn't like that I was using "type" in the PhoneType class. And also I changed the way I seeded the data to

```
        PhoneType a = new PhoneType()
        {
            phoneType = "cell"
        };

        a.Contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            fName = "Andra",
            lName = "Avram",
            phoneNumber = "438-881-5659"
        });

        context.PhoneTypes.Add(a);
        context.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(context);
```